# Raw HTML is being sent through my web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to implement an email verification system using `nodemailer` for my website but it is sending raw `html` to the users . Please Help

```
var html = '<h1>Hello !</h1><p>This is some content \
that will display. You can even inject your first name,  \
in the code.</p><p><a href="http://www.google.com">Search</a> for \
stuff on the Google website.</p>';
let mailOptions = {
  from: "abc@gmail.com", // TODO: email sender
  to: "example@gmail.com", // TODO: email receiver
  subject: "Account Verfication",
  text: html,
};

// Step 3
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, data) => {
  if (err) return log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending it as text. Use the "html" key instead. See https://nodemailer.com/message/

Answer (score 2):

Reference - https://nodemailer.com/about/ 
You need to use `html` key for `html` content.

```js
var html = '<h1>Hello !</h1><p>This is some content \
that will display. You can even inject your first name,  \
in the code.</p><p><a href="http://www.google.com">Search</a> for \
stuff on the Google website.</p>';
let mailOptions = {
  from: "abc@gmail.com", // TODO: email sender
  to: "example@gmail.com", // TODO: email receiver
  subject: "Account Verfication",
  html: html, // key should be html
};

// Step 3
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, data) => {
  if (err) return log(err);
});
```